# Final render keeps smoothing hard eyes

Tags: edges, smooth

I'm new in blender and I'm sure this is something really easy to fix but after looking for solutions I couldn't find any.

I have this models with hard edges but when I do the final render they get smoothed and more rounded, how can I turn off that so that in keeps looking like in the first image?

Thank you so much!

[image: Sharp Edges on Viewfinder]

[image: Smooth Edges on Render]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a subsurf modifier with different levels applied in the Viewport and Render.

Viewport:
[image]

Render:
[image]

Comment: This, or (since the viewport doesn't look very rounded at all) there is a _Subdivision Surface_ modifier simply turned off in the viewport and only showing in render.

Comment: That was it! Thank you both so much. You were so quick!!

Comment: No worries, can you mark the answer as accepted?

Comment: done! thanks yo so much